# "text-red-400 " is not responding in tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
<class="justify-between flex-1 text-3xl font-bold text-red-400 font-montserrat">
```

**text color not working in tailwind ,width is also not responding but max width is responding.
class text-red-500 is not being read. flex gap is not working what does that upperline trtind to do all other class is read instead of text-red-400. using tailwind version 3**
unable to change any text colour, percentage width also not working

**text color not working in tailwind ,width is also not responding but max width is responding.
class text-red-500 is not being read. flex gap is not working what does that upperline trtind to do all other class is read instead of text-red-400. using tailwind version 3**
unable to change any text colour, percentage width also not working

Comment: tailwind gone mad please help

Comment: Might be a good idea to add a larger snippet here, it's probably because of your general setup

Comment: share your tailwind.config.js file and this file also